# Do we need the "fastboot" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The Super User homepage just turned light blue for me, due to lots of hard-drive tags (which I have marked as a favourite). The reason was that a user had added the [fastboot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fastboot) tag to a bunch of posts.

"Fastboot" is a bit of a strange term - should we just replace it with the existing "boot" and/or "performance" tags, where appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of it's current use: No.
I think this was a case of a single user simply trying to use the term "fastboot" in an unusual way.

Given the absence of any other posts using the tag, I've done a straight merge from [fastboot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fastboot) to [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance), as that seems to be the gist of what they were after, and as such the four questions have now been changed behind the scenes.

Please note that I have *not* created a synonym at this time.

Comment: Thanks - it's unlikely that it'll pop up again anyway.